# Can an iOS application communicate with a Java application on my Mac via bluetooth without creating an OS X application?

Tags: java, ios, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have an iOS application with a tableview which I would like to send text strings via bluetooth to my Macbook indicating which cell was selected by the user. Both have bluetooth 4.0. This information will be fed into a Java application. From a CoreBluetooth perspective, the iOS device will be a peripheral and my Mac would be the central.

The problem I'm having is around setting up the central. Apple documentation gives a lot detail around building a central manager within a Mac OS X application (xcode, CBCentralManager). However, I'd like the data to be pulled into a Java application running on my Mac.

Do I need to build a Mac OS X application to wrap my Java application to build this type of communication? Should I consider another method of bluetooth communication i.e. BluetoothManager.Framework? I do not need to submit this to the Apple Store. Is this a TCP/IP problem?

Comment: I don't think your problem is closly related to Mac OS X. You'll probably have similar problem on Windows or Linux. I would try to investigate Bluetooth usage in Java in general.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/07/27/bluetooth.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My solution is based on [Ray Wenderlich's Network Tutorial for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21868). I created the python server, tethered my iOS device via bluetooth to my Mac, and transmitted messages via port 80 on my Bluetooth PAN IP address. Then I created a Java client to connect to the python server to receive the messages!